# ReactJS, Overlay on redirect with localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this redirect code:

```
if( 
        (
            this.props.userQuery.user && 
            this.props.userQuery.user.isMentee === true &&
            this.props.userQuery.user.email_verified === false
        ) ||
        (
            this.props.userQuery.user && 
            this.props.userQuery.user.isMentee === true &&
            this.props.userQuery.user.approved === false
        )
    ){
        return(
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/settings/profile/'
            }}/>

        )
    }
```

and I want to display this overlay message whenever the redirect happens ->

```
<div className="overlay-screen">
    <div className="action-panel">
    <h4 className="mb-2"><strong>Uh oh :(</strong></h4>
    <p>It looks like you haven't filled out your profile information yet. In order to ensure everyone has a great experience using our networking product, please make sure you fill out your profile information (avatar, bio, and social accounts) to provide our amazing mentors more information so they are able to learn more about you!</p>
    <p>If you are having any issues with updating your profile please <strong>start a live chat</strong> in the bottom right of the browser, or email <a href="mailto:help@designmentors.org">help@designmentors.org</a>.</p>
    <p><a className="button primary mb-2" href="/settings/profile">Update My Profile</a>.</p>
</div>
```

I need the overlay to show up whenever they get redirected. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have a couple ideas, either A. you can create a toast that shows the user what happened after the redirect or B.  you could render a Modal component that renders your overlay message but set a timeout in the componentDidMount hook that will call `history.push('/settings/profile/')` after a few seconds.